# Constantly asked for User Credentials when Accessing Windows Share from Mac

Tags: windows, macos, windows-xp

I connect to a Windows share successfully on a Mac using SMB, however every time I do it asks me to login as a guest or to enter my user credentials.

My Mac is on the domain and the Windows share I'm accessing is also on the same domain. When I access the file share from other Windows machines it automatically uses the domain credentials that the user is logged in as without any prompt. I am seeking the same functionality from my Mac but haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Is there a way to have my Mac automatically pass my credentials on for login without having to be prompted? The credentials are saved in my keychain but I still have to select the account to use and hit Ok.

The file share is setup on an XP box.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you already have it set this way or not, but if you have the same username and same password on Windows as you do on OS X, the connection should be seamless.